# Как применить generics вместо instanseof и явного приведения (java)?

Tags: java

Заранее извиняюсь, за нубство, приходится на лету и учиться и применять на практике недоученное/недопонятое
Есть вот такой метод:

```
public AdminPanel createAdmPanel(BaseRole someRole) {
if (someRole instanceof ChildRole1) {
    return new AdminPanel((ChildRole1) someRole);
} else {
    return new AdminPanel((ChildRole2) someRole);
}
```

}

BaseRole - родитель для ChildRole1 и ChildeRole2
В перегруженных конструкторах AdminPanel создаётся валидный объект для каждой роли. 
Мне не нравится явное приведение типов, как правильно воспользоваться дженериками?

Comment: У вас, скорее всего, проблемы в архитектуре. Покажите для начала класс AdminPanel с его конструкторами, а также хочется понять, что за роли. Это обычно что-то тривиальное  типа энама, а у вас это имеет иерархию...

Comment: Вот, постарался, чтобы ничего не выдернуть из контекста: https://github.com/KMA71/ToStackOvflQuest

Comment: Применение следующее: PageObject для тестирования веб-сайта (потому и говорю, что  не разраб). Т.е. есть классы, которые описывают страницу. Но для корректного прохождения тестов, каждый вариант страницы отличается для различных ролей. Поэтому возникла идея иметь один класс, а объекты создавать конкретно для каждой роли. Чтобы не писать "толстый" конструктор с приведением типов внутри, было решено воспользоваться перегрузкой конструктора. 
   При таком подходе у меня есть 1 класс для страницы и 1 тест (@CsvSourse, например), которые мне нужно поддерживать.

Answer (score 0):

Например такое приведение типов в дженериках:

```
public class  AdminPanel<T extends BaseRole> {

    private T test;

    public AdminPanel(T test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public static AdminPanel testMethod(BaseRole someRole){
        return new AdminPanel(someRole);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я пересмотрел ваш проект. У вас много лишнего кода, вы пытаетесь затолкать наследование там, где оно не надо. Всегда помните принцип KISS.

Итого, что получилось...

```
public enum Role {

    UNDERWRITER("Underwriter's constructor"), 
    SALE("Sale's constructor");

    private final String value;

    private Role (String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}

public class AdminPanel {

    private final Role role;

    public AdminPanel(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return role.getValue();
    }

}

public class TestCl {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(new AdminPanel(Role.SALE).getName());
        System.out.println(new AdminPanel(Role.UNDERWRITER).getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не совсем пойму, как будут вызываться разные конструкторы для AdminPanel. Дело в том, что мне нужно не только получить имя роли - мне нужно полностью инициализировать страницу: web-элементы могут иметь различное положение, для некоторых ролей могут быть доступны отдельные элементы, а клик на третьих будет также создавать различные страницы в зависимости от роли...

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь, возможно не совсем корректно вопрос задал, выкинув всю начинку. Старался оставить только суть: с каркасом метода, который я привёл в вопросе, всё прекрасно работает. Просто конструкция с instanceof и ифами не кажется хорошим решением. К тому же, иерархия ролей уже применяется, в несвязанных с сабжем местах.

Comment: Решение предложено исходя из изложенного вами кода. В примере , который вы привели, роли , а также класс LoginPage ничего не делают. То, что вы завязали на классы-роли гору кода - вообще не аргумент. Это привет от паттерна Low coupling. Из вашего кода следует, что сначала вы приводите роли к классу родителя (в методе TestCl) и передаете их в класс LoginPage, где тут же вызываете instanceof, чтобы узнать что за класс затолкали в класс родителя. Это выглядит странно. Если вы так жестко завязались на своих классах, то логично подумать про иерехию админпанели, а не про перегруженные конструкторы?

Comment: А еще подумайте вод над чем... Назначение конструктора - создание экземпляра класса и инициализация полей. Если у вас там гора логики, то это тоже не есть хорошо. В любом случае с кодом, который вы предоставили можно только гадать. Загрузите хотя бы указанные класс с полной их логикой, а то непонятно, что и зачем они далают.

Comment: В конструкторах у меня вообще нет никакой логики - они просто перегружаются. Используются как раз для создания экземпляра класса, гарантированно валидного для конкретной роли. И всё же, если отойти от архитектурных вопросов, как добавить синтаксического сахара - дженериков, вместо явного приведения типов в начальном вопросе? Если это возможно. Это я указал 2 штуки - в коде у меня уже 6 ифов(((

Comment: Дженерики здесь не работают, ваша задача не сделать метод (конструктор) универсальным для разных типов параметров(это задача для дженериков), а вызвать перегруженные разные методы (конструкторы). Единственное, чем могу помочь, это рефакторинг (для этого, конечно, надо смотреть код). Да и крутить костыль на ранее созданный костыль, потому как прошлый костыль работает плохо - так себе решение))